# Asp.net core 3.1 + Angular DNS Lookup Error - Frontend and backend can't communicate

Tags: angular, visual-studio, templates, asp.net-core, iis-express

I created a new Asp.net Core 3.1 with Angular, using the default template, and just hitted F5 to execute.

After npm packages are restored, the application didn't start correctelly, frontend and backend can't communicate between them.

Visual Studio start at https://localhost:5001 (ASP.NET API) and it should redirect to http://localhost:60433/ but instead of open a Hello World page, I receive this **504 DNS look up failed** error.

[image]

If I open http://localhost:60433/ it opens the Hello World page, it's served by `ng serve`. But calls to API (at localhost:5001) don't work. So it's not possible to login or to use Fetch Data (it calls WeatherForecast method of API)

[image]

But if I open https://localhost:5001/WeatherForecast  (after I removed `[Authorize]` in controller, it works!

[image]

The same project worked at my house, but fails at my company. 
Maybe it's a issue at my network, but I don't know where to start looking.

Anyone have any idea about this behavior?

Comment: Do the developer tools of the browser, specifically the console or the network analysis, provide any hints?

Comment: might be worth checking your `hosts` file and proxy settings. Sometimes companies install tools that would manage your proxy for you, I know [TMG client](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=10504) is one of them

Comment: actually, looking at your error screen - turn proxy off altogether in Chrome and try again?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Run this command from your command prompt.
   nslookup https://localhost:5001/
2. One solution would be to add this above url to hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts,

   Open your hosts file and add this line there
   127.0.0.1   https://localhost:5001/

Comment: Doens't work, still the same behavior. And `nslookup https://localhost:5001/` return domain not found.

Comment: Did you try the second one?